# Getting rid of cycle in bin index calculation

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is an [implementation of `HashMap`](http://en.literateprograms.org/Hash_table_%28Java%29#Adding_a_new_element).

It provides this code for getting index of the bin:

```
private int getIndex(K key)
{
    int hash = key.hashCode() % nodes.length;
    if (hash < 0)
        hash += nodes.length;
    return hash;
}
```

> To make sure the hash value is not bigger than the size of the table,
>   the result of the user provided hash function is used modulo the
>   length of the table. We need the index to be non-negative, **but the
>   modulus operator (%) will return a negative number if the left operand
>   (the hash value) is negative, so we have to test for it and make it
>   non-negative**.

If `hash` turns out to be very big negative value, the additions `hash += nodes.length` in the cycle may take a lot of processing.

I think there should be `O(1)` algorithm for it (independent of `hash` value).

If so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It can't be a very big negative number.**

The result of `anything % nodes.length` is always less that `nodes.length` in absolute value, so you need a single `if`, not a loop. This is exactly what the code does:

```
if (hash < 0) /* `if', not `while' */
    hash += nodes.length;
```

Comment: Oh. You are right. I missed `if` and always saw `while` instead. In the case of `if` it's already `O(1)`.

Answer (score 1):

This not the approach [HashMap](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html) uses in reality.

```
272       /**
273        * Returns index for hash code h.
274        */
275       static int indexFor(int h, int length) {
276           return h & (length-1);
277       }
```

This works because `length` is always a power of 2 and this is the same an *unsigned* `% length`

> If hash turns out to be very big negative value, the additions hash += nodes.length in the cycle may take a lot of processing.

The hash at this point must be between `-length+1` and `length-1` so it cannot be a very large negative value and the code wouldn't work if it did.  In any case it doesn't matter how large the value is, the cost is always the same.

Comment: Great trick with bitwise AND. But it will only work if `length` is a power of 2. Why does this condition hold?

Comment: When `length` is a power of 2, one less than this is a number like 000...000111..111 i.e. a block of 0's and a block of 1's which means the top bits are discarded which serves the same purpose as `%` except it's unsigned as the top bit is discarded and much faster because its simple.

Comment: BTW A related piece of code is this to test that a number is a power of two `n != 0 && (n & (n-1)) == 0` ;)

Comment: I got the trick with the bits from your answer. But I didn't get why `length` is a power of 2. Now I see that if we need to test n for being a power of 2, it doesn't hold always. So, I guess, for this algorithm to work we should ensure that length is always a power of 2.

Comment: @ovgolovin Its is always a power of 2 because the code ensures that it is. See the constructor for HashMap. ;)